# Scraping webpage after DOM is manipulated by JavaScript

Tags: javascript, c#, html, web-scraping, html-agility-pack

I'm scraping a webpage using C# in Visual Studio with Html Agility Pack.

It's very straightforward, but I'm trying to scrape the table on this page:
http://www.nasdaqomxnordic.com/Investeringsbeviser

The problem is (I think), that the table is created in javascript and the table is not created before the Selectnodes-function does its work. There is no table-tags to be found in the output from Selectnodes (and I know it works, because I can find other tags using this method)

I think I have to get Visual Studio to interpret the javascript before the Selectnodes-function kicks in, but I don¨t know how to.

I have searched and searched, but no-one seems to have gotten the same problem.

Any help would be very welcome.

Best Regards

Jon